# Why am I not receiving Notification for Pending Approval in my Azure DevOps Server CD?

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I've created a pre-deployment step in our Azure DevOps 2019 Server to request approval before proceeding. The release works as intended once I approve it within the DevOps system, but no email requesting approval is ever sent out.

I have googled this ad nauseam and carefully looked over the recommended articles when I created this question so I'm pretty stumped on what to even check next at this point.

Here is a run down of the things I've tried:

GLOBAL LEVEL

1. Organization Settings --> Global Notifications
2. Verified all default subscriptions are enabled
3. Subscribers --> Added myself to all notifications
4. Settings --> Ensured "Deliver to Individual Members" is checked

PROJECT LEVEL

1. (For the project with the pipeline in question) Project Settings --> Notifications
2. Verified that all Notification types are enabled and set to "Individual Members".
   (Now that I'm looking at this, based on the configuration, my team should be getting spammed with emails...Not a single one is going out)

PERSONAL/USER LEVEL

1. User Icon --> Notifications
2. Verified all subscriptions are enabled

I realize that all of this will probably generate loads of emails. Right now, I'm just trying to get the emails to actually go out. We're new to DevOps so we're just muddling our way through things and docs and youtube for each piece we need and Continuous Deployment is the latest bit I'm digging into. I'm also an administrator on the Organization and the project in question that I'm trying to get this to work with.

I'm open to any thoughts the community might have or any direction you could provide on what I should troubleshoot next. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I hadn't checked this. I've fought this for 4 days. I finally did check on how to verify/setup STMP settings in devops (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/setup-customize-alerts?view=azure-devops-2020). None were specified.

/FACEPALM

I put in our SMTP details and the notifications worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this issue. Please follow below steps to check the `Notifications settings`.

In the `Global Notifications` under `Organization Settings`, pleaes make sure c`Deployment approval pending` is enabled.

[image]

Go to `Notifications` under `Project Settings`. Please make sure above notification `Deployment approval pending` is there too.

[image]

If you have check above settings are correctly set up. But you still fail to receive the email. You can try [creating a custom subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled#add-a-custom-subscription). See below steps.

Navigate to `Notifications` under `Project Settings`--> Click `New Subscription`

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have checked all of these settings and they match what I see in my configuration. I also added the subscription to the project as directed, but I am still not seeing any emails.

Is there some way I can check that the devops server can actually send out emails or specify the smtp server for the DevOps server? I did not set up the server.