# Predeployment approval in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Unable to approve the predeployment process in azure devops in production stage, User is notified with the mail but there is no approve option when logged in.

Comment: Could you please let us know if the answer is helpful. If the provided solution worked, could you please Upvote and accept it as answer to help other community members for the similar issue. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one of workaround :

- In the dev/production stage make sure that you have enabled the pre deployment approvals  and assigned user from configuration

[image]

- Enabled and assigned the user :

[image]

- Then you can receive an  email like this .

[image]

For more information please refer this MS DOC: [Define your Classic pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops) & [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66908960/why-am-i-not-receiving-notification-for-pending-approval-in-my-azure-devops-serv)

Answer (score 0):

In the dev/production stage make sure that you have enabled the pre deployment approvals and assigned user from configuration

Comment: Isn't this already covered by @AjayKumarGhose's original answer, but with far more detail?